# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name where is it looking in Active directory?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have an application that has windows integrated authentication turned on.
But for some users the following returns empty

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

where as for others it returns their login user id.

Where is it looking in Active directory?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, when a user logs onto your domain controller they're authenticated. This information is passed along to your app along with the web request and is accessible via HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name as well as a few other places (Thread.CurrentThread and the like).

In any event, if your user is coming up with a null HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name then they're not authenticated. This likely means they're coming off of some extranet or some other environment which doesn't communicate with your domain controllers.

[Here is the relevant document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx) explaining the details. I'd post it all here, but it's MSDN and unlikely to go away anytime soon.

Comment: the users who are having issues are longing in and being authenticated by the domain controller.  Which is why it's very confusing atm

Comment: As far as I know, if they were being authenticated by the same domain controller in communication with your web server, they wouldn't have a null Identity.Name. Extranet, VPN, etc involved? Basically, the token isn't being passed by the user one way or another.